# Migrar de JKS a PKCS12

Tags: android

Hoy llegó el momento de generar la apk. Las usar Android Studio cuando genero mi clave dice:

> El almacén de claves JKS utiliza un formato propietario. Se recomienda migrar a PKCS12, que es un formato estándar del sector que utiliza "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\PC\Google Drive\Proyectos_Android_Studio\keystore\HilosAppKey.jks -destkeystore C:\Users\PC\Google Drive\Proyectos_Android_Studio\keystore\HilosAppKey.jks -deststoretype pkcs12

Con cmd voy a la carpeta que contiene el keeytool.exe y hago:

```
keytool
    -importkeystore 
    -srckeystore C:\Users\PC\Google Drive\Proyectos_Android_Studio\keystore\HilosAppKey.jks
    -destkeystore C:\Users\PC\Google Drive\Proyectos_Android_Studio\keystore\HilosAppKey.jks 
    -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Devuelve error:

```
Opcion no permitida: \Google Drive\Proyectos_Android_Studio\keystore\HilosAppKey.jks
```

Bueno si alguien puede darme una mano, probe cargar la apk generada en mi movil y da error al cargarla, no se si es por lo anterior o es otra cosa.
Aclaro que cuando la corro desde AS con el movil en modo depuracion USB siempre anda.

Lo soulcione quitandolo de dentro de la carpeta Googledrive, aunque estaba pausada parece que aveces no deja guardar cambios y esta vez vía consola no hay aviso de esto

Answer (score 1):

La operación completa es:

```
keytool 
    -importkeystore 
    -srckeystore myapp.jks 
    -destkeystore myapp.p12 
    -srcalias myapp-dev 
    -srcstoretype jks 
    -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Te falta indicar el alias de la llave que queres mover al nuevo keystore, el tipo de entrada y el de salida.

Comment: La verdad que poniendo la línea de comando completa que el mismo Android Studio genera junto con la advertencia alcanza. Como edité  al final de mi consulta con sacarlo de dentro de la carpeta de mi google drive solucione el error que daba al intentar migrar.

Answer (score 1):

Poniendo por consola la línea de comando completa que el mismo Android Studio genera junto con la advertencia es suficiente.

Por otro lado puede haber problemas si esta dentro de tu carpeta GoogleDrive aunque este pausada o cerrada, al moverme fuera de GoogleDrive se eliminimo el error adicional que me daba.

Recordar que cuando pida la clave por consola el cursor no avanza al teclear la key solicitada pero ingresarla igual. En mi propia pregunta agregué al final esto mismo.