# Error con el APK Android

Tags: android, apk

Hola tengo un error al querer firmar y generar mi APK... si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería

> Key was created with errors:

> Warning:
> El almacén de claves JKS utiliza un formato propietario. Se recomienda migrar a PKCS12, que es un formato estándar del sector que utiliza "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore D:\LV-SISTEMAS IT\Proyectos App\Android App Bundle\autotint_apk_bundle.jks -destkeystore D:\LV-SISTEMAS IT\Proyectos App\Android App Bundle\autotint_apk_bundle.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".

Comment: Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/319208/822 es la misma pregunta y hay algunas respuestas. Saludos

Comment: sobre que IDE estas trabajando?

Answer (score 0):

Este es un problema de compatibilidad entre la version de java y la version/formato de la clave creada. Esta indicando que la clave fue creada con formato JKS, EL mismo mensaje te da una solucion que es convertir la clave a PKCS12:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "D:\LV-SISTEMAS IT\Proyectos App\Android App Bundle\autotint_apk_bundle.jks" -destkeystore "D:\LV-SISTEMAS IT\Proyectos App\Android App Bundle\autotint_apk_bundle.jks" -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Esto supone que la herramienta `keytool` esta disponible en tu ruta de ejecucion (PATH), sino debes ubicar el ejecutable dentro de la carpeta `bin` del la distribucion de JDK que tengas instalada.

Adicional a esto, te recomiendo que revises que version de java tienes instalada (`java -version`) y que version de JDK usas para crear las claves.